# Adding an ActiveX control to a tab Page

Tags: c#, winforms

This is the code I am using:

```
tabPage1.Controls.Add(AXViewer1);
```

where AXViewer1 is a third party ActiveX control (non .NET) that I want to add to my tab page.

Is it wrong to do it the way I did, since it has not added it to the tab page with that code?

Comment: Please show us more code.  What exactly happens?

Comment: all the code is that one line that I posted.
here is what I have done so far:
- dropped a TabControl on the form.
- dropped that ActiveX control on the form
- running that code: tabPage1.Controls.Add(AXViewer1);
- what happens: nothing! it does not show in TabPage

Answer (score 1):

Your ActiveX control probably cannot be reparented at runtime.

You need to create a new instance of the class at runtime by writing `new AXViewer()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the Visible property to True. Also try calling the CreateHandle method.

If none of this works, you are best off contacting the developer of the ActiveX control for support.